# Paypal Express checkout pay as guest for subscription

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, express-checkout

I want to create a subscription using paypal Expresscheckout method. In that I want my users to pay as a guest using their credit card.

I tried `Solutiontype = sole` . But its working only on Single purchases not working on subscription.

Is there anything do I need to change in my code or in my settings.

(note: I have enabled the optional paypal account in settings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Guest checkout" is not an option for Subscription payments unless you have the "Enhanced Recurring Payments" feature added to your account.